# WHERE clause on SQL Server "Text" data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Where [CastleType] is set as data type "text" in SQL Server and the query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [Village]
WHERE  [CastleType] = 'foo'
```

I get the error:

> The data types **TEXT** and **VARCHAR** are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Can I not query this data type with a WHERE clause?

Comment: Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `TEXT` - that datatype is deprecated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888243/the-data-types-text-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator-in-c-s)

Answer (score 111):

You can use `LIKE` instead of `=`. Without any wildcards this will have the same effect.

```
DECLARE @Village TABLE
        (CastleType TEXT)

INSERT INTO @Village
VALUES
  (
    'foo'
  )

SELECT *
FROM   @Village
WHERE  [CastleType] LIKE 'foo'
```

`text` is deprecated. Changing to `varchar(max)` will be easier to work with.

Also how large is the data likely to be? If you are going to be doing equality comparisons you will ideally want to index this column. This isn't possible if you declare the column as anything wider than 900 bytes though you can add a computed `checksum` or `hash` column that can be used to speed this type of query up.

Answer (score 28):

Please try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   [Village]
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, CastleType) = 'foo'
```

Comment: This also is useful to be able to directly see the data in the TEXT field if you are using some tools like Toad for Sql Server that protect BLOB type fields to be seen at the first execution. You can always click the field to tell Toad to show the field, but it's a two step procedure.

Comment: Note that this will probably make your query [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Answer (score 14):

You can't compare against `text` with the `=` operator, but instead must used one of the comparison functions listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).  Also note the large warning box at the top of the page, it's important.

Answer (score 7):

If you can't change the datatype on the table itself to use varchar(max), then change your query to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [Village]
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [CastleType]) = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not what the error message says. It says that you cannot use the `=` operator. Try for instance `LIKE 'foo'`.

Comment: `Col IN ('foo', 'bar')` is basically the same as `Col = 'foo' or Col = 'bar'` and will have the same problem.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the highlight, I didn't know about it. I'll correct it then.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
SELECT * FROM [Village] WHERE PATINDEX('foo', [CastleType]) <> 0
```

Comment: I suspect that `like 'foo'` might give better cardinality estimates than this approach but am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Martin: Since you can't index a TEXT column, I think you'll end up with a full table scan in either case.

Comment: I agree but it will still use statistics on the column to get an estimate of the rows that will be returned which might affect join decisions etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works in MSSQL and MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Village
WHERE  CastleType LIKE '%foo%';
```

Comment: OP is using MSSQL not MySQL.