# Error executing select query

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, exception, ado.net

I have a simple select query but executing it gives me an error:

> Datatypes text and varchar incompatible in the equal to operator

Here is the code:

```
string query = String.Format("Select SupplierId from tbl_Supplier where SupplierName ='" + cmbSupplierName.Text +"'");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (sdr.Read())
{
   MessageBox.Show(sdr["SupplierId"].ToString());
}
```

The datatype for `SupplierName` is `TEXT` in the database. I am not getting why it gives me error for `varchar`

Comment: here's the clue ---> " text and varchar not compatible". They're not. That's the problem. 'Text' isn't what it sounds like...

Comment: I am looking for the problem in my query. I very well know they are not compatible

Comment: I'm guessing the user can type into the TextBox. By creating the SQL statement by string concatenation like this - you're opening yourself to performance and security issues. Please read up on SQL injection. The correct way to do this would be adding parameters to your `SqlCommand`.

Comment: But to solve your problem - try casting the `SupplierName` column to a varchar (or nvarchar) datatype.

Comment: i tried that but the same error

Comment: Use Like '%Text_here' instead of equality operator.

Comment: text is deprecated, you shouldn't use it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [WHERE clause on SQL Server "Text" data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350060/where-clause-on-sql-server-text-data-type)

Comment: Insert Obligatory SQL Injection Warning....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SupplierName is really a text field, try:

```
cast(SupplierName as varchar(max)) = '...'
```

Text is an [old and deprecated column type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).  Back in the days, it could contain more than 8000 characters, more than `varchar`.  Since SQL Server 2005 that role is better filled by `varchar(max)`.

It would be an amazing supplier that has a name with more than 8000 characters though.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe i'm missing something, but the first thing is:

1. open your Connection before you use it

Apart from that,

- use Parameters to avoid SQL-Injection
- use `using-statement` to dispose/close the connection and the command(anything implementing `IDispoable)`
- use `VARCHAR` instead of `TEXT` if the maximum length is less than 8000 chars, otherwise you need to use `LIKE` instead of `=` (or cast it to `VARCHAR`)

> "Comparison operators test whether two expressions are the same.
>   Comparison operators can be used on all expressions except expressions
>   of the text, ntext, or image data types. The following table lists the
>   Transact-SQL comparison operators."

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/6bd4c661-ea0b-435f-af78-097e61549d41/