# TSQLT unit test - The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: t-sql, tdd, sql-server-2008-r2, tsqlt

I am getting this error from AssertEqualsTable "The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator."

then

"The 'TableCompare' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead."

```
select   *
    into #Actual
    from [dbo].[InvoiceOut];

--make expected table an empty table of #actual's structure because we truncate so it should be empty.
    SELECT TOP(0) *
    INTO #Expected
    FROM #Actual;

EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable '#Expected', '#Actual';
```

--part of the relevant table info

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceOut](
...
    [InsertField] [text] NULL,
    [DeductibleText] [text] NULL,
    [BarcodeText] [text] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You should not still be using text datatype, it is deprecated. This is a problem with your data structure that is CRITICAL to fix.

Comment: can you explain why it is CRITICAL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE clause on SQL Server "Text" data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350060/where-clause-on-sql-server-text-data-type)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888243/the-data-types-text-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator-in-c-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can compare text field values, which would explain the error.

Also, the text data type is deprecated in favor of varchar(MAX).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type)