# The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, casting

I have a series of tables with fields that i can't change. The first table has one field I have list numbers (entitled `list_no type int`) and in another i have a field called `criteria type text.`

For some reason you can't compare into to criteria so i had to cast it as a `varchar(max).` Here is my code sample. This isn't the most efficiently written code, but i need a quick turn around on the data and i'm having a hard time.

```
select distinct CAST(list_no as varchar(max)) as v_lists
into #temp
from table_list 
where created_by = 'user1' 

select cast(v_lists as text) as t_text into #temp2 from #temp

select * 
from table_keys
where criteria = (select cast(t_text as text) from #temp2)
```

basically criteria is a long series of text fields in which my list_no may or may not appear as part of a string. I was able to successfully convert it to a text field but i'm still getting this error:

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```

I am confused -- why wont this work? I can't do this one at a time because in the first scenario i have about 25 lists. But i will have to run this code for about 10 users and some have hundreds of lists. so coding out one at a time isn't practical.

please advise.

Comment: What is the data stored as in `table_keys`?

Comment: @ajwinchell a lot of data about lists that are part of larger groupings of lists. but each row is a segment which has criteria about what order its in, the name of that segment, priority in which it is run followed by 5 of these criteria fields each having possible bits of logic. as well as a bunch of other stuff? (its a huge table)

Comment: And why not just use `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i tried using varchar(max). I need to say give me all the rows where my list_no could be in the criteria field ... so nested select. but that doesn't seem to work with text/text or text/varchar(max)

Comment: are you sure you don't want `criteria in (select value from table)` instead of `=`

Comment: @scsimon = would work in a one at a time scenario but i have as i mentioned in a simple case 25 possible lists, on a larger scale hundreds and i want to pull all of them in one shot.

Comment: should this be `select * 
from table_keys
where cast(criteria as varchar(max)) = (select cast(t_text as varchar(max)) from #temp2)`  or simply join with cast to varchar(max)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TSQLT unit test - The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285130/tsqlt-unit-test-the-data-types-text-and-text-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to)