# 'condition is expected' in query

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Projects\\csharp\\Login1\\App_Data\\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader dr;   

protected void  LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 conn.Open();
 cmd=new SqlCommand("Select * from LoginTable where User Name='"+TextBox1.Text+"'",conn);
 dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();   //  <---error here

 if(dr.Read())
 {
   Label1.Text="User name already exist";
   this.Label1.ForeColor=Color.Red;
 }
 else
 {
   Label1.Text="Name available";
 }
}
```

It shows the following error near `dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();`:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'Name'.

Whats happening here

Comment: User Name? It should be UserName. Remove the space

Comment: Try specifiying bracket for Column `User Name` because it contains space.
`("Select * from LoginTable where [User Name] = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'",conn);`

Comment: try using [username] instead of User name

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `User Name` in where clause with `[User Name]`

Comment: After changing i get this at same point ------------ The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350060/where-clause-on-sql-server-text-data-type

Answer (score 3):

The user name must be specified as **[User Name]** or **UserName** so please check column name once

Answer (score 2):

User Name consists of two words. And also use parameterized query.

```
cmd=new SqlCommand("Select * from LoginTable where [User Name]=@userName",conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not give space between `UserName` in this statement:

```
cmd=new SqlCommand("Select * from LoginTable where **User Name** = '"+TextBox1.Text+"'", conn);
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the possible typo in the field name (UserName?), this is not how it should be done.
Try this:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM LoginTable where [User Name]=@p)" +
"SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", TextBox1.Text);

if(Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar()))
{
   Label1.Text="User name already exist";
   this.Label1.ForeColor=Color.Red;
}
else
   Label1.Text="Name available";
```

Answer (score 2):

The user name must be specified as [User Name] or UserName so please check column name once

and also check for reserved keywords if you use them as column names please kept in square brasses **[ ]**

```
cmd=new SqlCommand("Select * from LoginTable where [User Name] = @userName",conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", TextBox1.Text);
```

**OR**

```
cmd=new SqlCommand("Select * from LoginTable where UserName = @userName",conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", TextBox1.Text);
```