# SQL Server : 'Case When' Statement to Replace Strings With Other Strings Not Working

Tags: sql-server, string, replace, case

Below is the T-SQL code I currently am running. My goal is to replace certain strings in the `RRR` column with other strings.

The code executes but the strings are not getting replaced. Original string values still in data.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
       WHEN [RRR] = 'A' THEN 'Apple'   
       WHEN [RRR] = 'A-9' THEN 'A9'
       WHEN [RRR] = 'BASE' THEN 'B'
       WHEN [RRR] = 'CHECK' THEN 'B'
       ELSE [RRR]
    END AS CleanDataAMES4 
INTO #df_ERA4_a_temp
FROM #df_ERA4_a
```

Comment: Are the comparison strings exactly the same (e.g., case?)

Comment: Just checking, that 'original data', is that the RRR column (because of the *), or the cleandataAMES4 column?

Comment: original column is RRR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), RRR TEXT);
INSERT INTO test (RRR) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('A-9'),('BASE'),('CHECK');

SELECT *,
CASE 
   WHEN RRR LIKE 'A' THEN 'Apple'   
   WHEN RRR LIKE 'A-9' THEN 'A9'
   WHEN RRR LIKE 'BASE' THEN 'B'
   WHEN RRR LIKE 'CHECK' THEN 'B'
   ELSE RRR
   END AS CleanDataAMES4
FROM test;
```

Use "LIKE" instead of "=".

Your problem is the "=" operator. I think that the error message 'The data types TEXT and VARCHAR are incompatible in the equal to operator.' is not displayed because it occurs within your CASE statement. [Look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350060/where-clause-on-sql-server-text-data-type).

You can try this in [sqlfidde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/14840/2)

Comment: But why would you then accept my answer, if it didn't solve your problem?

Comment: I see. Good for you. Just in case you want to dive deeper into this issue. You should look into how you compare texts in MSSQL. Also there are multiple "text" types in MSSQL so you'll eventually have to use casts as well.