# Replacing a space-looking character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, space

I have a database backup that I restored in SQL Server 2014 and I am using SQL Server Management Studio 18 (15.0.18206.0)

In a column of type `text` strings of XML files are stored. Yes, I know that the datatype `text` is obsolete. But I cannot change the datatype in the old program so easily.

Now I want to remove the string `<SCHNITTLINIE>`.

In the cell, it looks like this: `..._MIN>  <SCHNITTLINIE>  <S...`

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '<SCHNITTLINIE>', '') AS TEXT)
FROM [dbo].[XMLdatei]
WHERE xml LIKE '%SCHNITTLINIE%'.
```

As a result, I get: `...MIN>    <S...`

So far so good.

I'd like to remove the "spaces" as well.

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ' <SCHNITTLINIE> ', '') AS TEXT)
FROM [dbo].[XMLdatei]
WHERE xml LIKE '%SCHNITTLINIE%'
```

Now he finds the string '  ' but not anymore.

At the beginning of the cell is a `<?xml version="1.0"`. So I tried the following to test the spaces:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'xml ', 'xxx') AS TEXT)
FROM .[dbo].[XMLdatei].
WHERE xml LIKE '%SCHNITT%'.
```

As a result I got the following: `<?xxxversion="1.0"`

The following also works:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'xml' + char(32), 'xxx') AS TEXT)
FROM [dbo].[XMLdatei]
WHERE xml LIKE '%SCHNITT%'
```

Check, the test was successful. :)

Only with the string `' <SCHNITTLINIE> '` this does not work.

- How can I find out what the characters before `<` or after `>` are?
- How can I remove them without knowing what the characters are?

Thanks for your help.

Have a nice weekend.

Christoph

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350060/where-clause-on-sql-server-text-data-type) on working with `text` fields

Comment: I'll point out that there is a difference between TEXT and NTEXT. Don't add to the confusion by converting between ascii and unicode without reason. And if you want to "see" what the non-visible characters are, cast it (all or part depending on the length and any segment of interest) to varbinary.

Comment: `convert()` to `varchar(max)`, then use `substring()` to get the character and then `ascii()` to find the ascii code